# react trading view widget how to stop scroll on mouse wheel up down

Tags: reactjs, tradingview-api, react-scroll

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am using react trading view widget my client requirement is that it should stop scrolling on fixed button press. I have used this approach but its stopped all mouse events

i need just stop scrolling on chart its serious issue  please help:

chartPosition is a state that will change on fixed button pressed just remember this

```
const NewBoard = ({ ticker, theme, selectedTime, chartPosition }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="custom-range"
      style={
        chartPosition === "Fixed"
          ? { pointerEvents: "none", height: "75%" }
          : { pointerEvents: "initial", height: "75%" }
      }
    >
      <TradingViewWidget
        id="my_view"
        symbol={ticker}
        theme={theme === "LIGHT" ? Themes.LIGTH : Themes.DARK}
        locale="eng"
        interval={selectedTime}
        autosize={true}
        range={`${chartPosition === "Fixed" ? "ytd" : "all"}`}
        // withdateranges={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I want to stop scrolling  inside the chart
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KfTp.png

Comment: see this link : `https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/`

Answer (score 0):

You just must set `overflow: hidden` :

```
const NewBoard = ({ ticker, theme, selectedTime, chartPosition }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={"custom-range " + chartPosition ? "disable-scroll" : ""}
      style={{ overflow: chartPosition === "Fixed" ? "hidden" : "initial", height: "75%" }}
    >
      <TradingViewWidget
        id="my_view"
        symbol={ticker}
        theme={theme === "LIGHT" ? Themes.LIGTH : Themes.DARK}
        locale="eng"
        interval={selectedTime}
        autosize={true}
        range={`${chartPosition === "Fixed" ? "ytd" : "all"}`}
        // withdateranges={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

and put this style inside a css file that is imported to your page:

```
.disable-scroll .chart-container { pointer-events: none }
```

Comment: Not working please review the  question

Comment: What is className of div that has scroll in chart?

Comment: problem is its inside  the iframe  and inside the canvas we can't get it

Comment: I add a classname to the div and you can style it: `.disable-scroll iframe  canvas { overflow: "hidden"}`

Comment: is its working ?

Comment: But all canvas inside of your chart take the style. if the canvas has a id use that id instead of canvas.

Comment: You should check it cause I don't have access to your code

Comment: react-tradingview-widget here is the package  you  can test here  it

Comment: its not overflowing i want to stop zoom in out on scroll not overflow

Comment: Probably your style will work on it: `.disable-scroll iframe  canvas { pointerEvents: none }`

Comment: check this: `.disable-scroll .chart-container { pointer-events: none }` put this inside of a CSS file

Comment: pointer event none  stoped  click event also i want click event just to stop zoom in out

Comment: thanks for your collaboration but i need just to stop  zoom event

Comment: i have  used these already

Comment: and i think we can't get the classes inside the iframe

Comment: TradingViewWidget doesn't have a attribute like zoom that take a boolean value?

Comment: no its don't have any attribute  like  this